# Android WifiInfo.getRSSI providing strange results while device is asleep

Tags: android, wifi, device, sleep, rssi

I have a simple `IntentService` which is started with `startWakefulService`. The service has a for loop which gets the RSSI every 3000ms, as such:

```
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        if (wifiInfo != null && wifiManager != null){
            Log.i(TAG, "wifiInfo, RSSI: " + wifiInfo.getRssi());
        }

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
```

While the device is sleeping (screen is off) the method `WifiInfo.getRSSI` always returns the same value (example: -58) even when I move the device around.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you thinks that could be the last value that was returned before the device went to sleep, and the service isn't updating while the the screen is off?

Comment: @tallpaul It does seem that it is returning the last value before the device went to sleep. However, the service is successfully created and destroyed at the set interval, even when the screen is off, so I don't see why this would be the case.